# Понятие «модератор»

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация

Привилегированные действия пользователей с репутацией ≥500 на сайтах Stack Exchange называются [«модерацией»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). В то же время «модераторы» — [пользователи с высочайшим уровнем привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) в рамках сообщества. Во избежание путаницы, которая будет сопровождать понятия все годы существования русскоязычного Stack Overflow, предложил бы переименовать «модераторов», например, как везде — в «администраторов».

Answer (score 4):

Заметка на странице выборов немного неоднозначна. Модераторы не имеют высочайшего уровня привилегий вообще, "в рамках сообщества" здесь означает "по сравнению с другими обычными участниками сайта, но не с сотрудниками компании".

> Привилегированные действия пользователей с репутацией ≥500 на сайтах Stack Exchange называются «модерацией».

Тут тоже стоит уточнить. Действительно, сайты сети SE устроены так, что у всех пользователей есть возможности влиять на качество содержимого сайта и поведение участников. По мере роста репутации эти возможности расширяются. Но далеко не все привилегированные действия являются модерацией. К ней можно отнести очереди проверок, тревоги, голоса за закрытие вопросов, в некоторой степени голоса за и против. Но доступ к статистике, просмотр удаленных сообщений, правки без инспекции - это не модерация.

Модератор - это просто участник, который:

1. Получил сразу все привилегии по модерации, доступные другим участникам за репутацию (а также все остальные привилегии за репутацию).
2. Получил ещё немного инструментов модерации, которые доступны только сотрудникам.
3. Взял на себя обязательство использовать эти возможности во благо сообщества.

Т.е. все участники модерируют, но обязаны это делать только модераторы. Аналогично с вождением автомобиля: права есть у многих, автомобиль водят многие, но "водителем" обычно называют того, кто занимается этим профессионально.

Comment: Извиняюсь, «некоторые» перед «привилегированные действия» забыл указать. Спасибо.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что есть реальные админы, причём тоже разных уровней. Про "высочайший уровень привилегий" я уже писал, кстати, только мне сказали, что в английской версии такой же косяк, так что пусть остаётся. Х)

Comment: @Discord ага, администратор - это отдельная задача. Это скорее управление развитием сообщества, чем контроль ежедневных процессов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Положим, на уровне многих движков админ — это просто пользователь с самыми высокими привилегиями. Да и админ в винде — тоже управляющий что ли? Судя по тексту вопроса, подразумевается именно значение с уровнем привилегий.

Comment: @Discord есть ещё такой аспект: администратор обычно может управлять привилегиями других пользователей, в частности повышать их (например, поднять до модератора), а модератор - не может (только ограничить доступ).